# How to read an image in Scilab

Tags: image-processing, matlab

In Matlab we use below function to read an image :

```
var = imread('IMAGE‌‌ ‌PATH');
```

But, how to do same thing in Scilab ?

Comment: Z= imread('image path');

Comment: For scilab 6.0 use: atomsInstall("IPCV"); imread('my.jpg')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scilab Image and Video Processing toolbox](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/SIVP) provides [imread()](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/func-list-0.5.0/imread.htm) function.

The related [How To entry](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/doc.php#image_read) gives example and it's similar to Matlab:

```
im=imread(filename);
```

See [ATOMS](http://wiki.scilab.org/ATOMS) article to learn how to install additional modules in Scilab.

Comment: For scilab 6.0 use: atomsInstall("IPCV") instead.